# JSHINT error: Expected 'combine' to have an indentation at 9 instead at 13

Tags: emacs, jslint, wsh, jshint, jscript

I like the idea behind JSLINT but sometimes it is a little too strict, in my opinion needlessly so.

Recently I found JSHINT. It's a little more flexible, allows more options to be turned on or off.

But JSHINT is throwing an error on code that I think looks right.  For example, JSHINT barfs on its own code. If I run JSHINT on JSHINT.js, it gives me this:

[image]

I don't understand that.  See the error message near the bottom of that image?  JSHINT seems to want the indentation to be different than it is.  It's not complaining about the lack of the curly. I have `curly:false` which says to not require curlies around one-liner if statements.

The odd thing is, JSHINT.js source code uses a 4-space indent everywhere, but it throws errors about the indent only for these few lines.  Why?

Am I doing this wrong?  Is there something else I should be configuring?

---

**EDITED**  - originally I had been playing around with JSHINT, and I put the `combine()` call on the same line as the if statement. I've reverted the JSHINT code back to what it was originally, to show that the errors remain.

[image]

This is done with JSHINT using these options:

```
options = {
    curly      : false, // no curly fascism
    wsh        : true,  // WScript is allowed
    white      : true,  // true: 'sloppy' whitespace is ok
    plusplus   : false, // false == ok to use ++
    passfail   : false  // do not stop after first error
    //radix      : true   // do not puke on parseInt() with no radix
};
```

---

**EDIT2**

Here's a gif that shows what JSHINT, in its original form, really wants.  When the red highlights disappear, it means JSHINT is happy for that particular line. (This is using [flymake-for-jslint](http://code.google.com/p/jslint-for-wsh/downloads/list) in emacs).

[image]

As you can see, if I indent the line in an odd way, JSHINT relaxes.

## Answer

I think the answer is in [this github issue](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/87). I modified JSHINT, line 2264, like this:

```
***************
*** 2256,2262 ****
--- 2261,2270 ----
                          nexttoken, '{', nexttoken.value);

              noreach = true;
+             // cheeso - fix for https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/87
+             indent += option.indent;
              a = [statement()];
+             indent = old_indent;
              noreach = false;
          }
```

...and it stopped complaining about its own formatting.

Comment: \*points\* The first if statement has it's execution code on the same line as the if keyword... could that be it?

Comment: Yes, Joseph, that's true. The error for the first one is because the code is on the same line as the if statement.  I've updated the question to show what I mean more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is in [this github issue][4]. I modified JSHINT, line 2264, like this:

```
***************
*** 2256,2262 ****
--- 2261,2270 ----
                          nexttoken, '{', nexttoken.value);

              noreach = true;
+             // cheeso - fix for https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/87
+             indent += option.indent;
              a = [statement()];
+             indent = old_indent;
              noreach = false;
          }
```

...and it stopped complaining about its own formatting.

Answer (score 2):

JSHint maintainer here. Based on your screenshot, it errors because the `combine` is on the same line as your `if` clause which is against `white` option's rules.

Are you sure that your copy of JSHint was not modified by anybody? We have unit tests for JSHint and one of the tests checks JSHint's own source code with itself. And, as you can see from the attached example, everything passes just fine.

[image: jshint passing jshint screenshot]

Comment: Hey, nice to meet you.  No - the issue of having combine on the same line, I understand. but look at the other red-highlighted lines in that screenshot. Those are all indications that JSHINT is complaining about the indentation. If I fix the first one, all the others remain.  I found this post:  https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/87 which seems to be similar.  I then modified modified JSHINT.js, line 2264 in my version, with those changes, and it stopped complaining. What do you think?

Comment: And to answer your question, YES, I modified the JSHINT.js code by appending some boilerplate to allow JSHINT.js to read its input from the command line, on Windows running via WSH. It doesn't change any of the JSHINT.js code - only appends. And sets options.   You can find it at http://code.google.com/p/jslint-for-wsh/downloads/list

Comment: I checked the latest master and realized that I removed the `white` option from JSHint's source. This option is a legacy from Crockford's JSLint and I don't use it.

Comment: ok, so...... what does that mean, for me? Am I doing something wrong in setting the options? The changes suggested in issue #87 - are those changes correct? They seem to work for me but I don't have the test suite.

Comment: Haven't looked at that ticket yet, will do next week and update the ticket. If you use `white` option you are basically telling JSHint to treat your code per Crockford's Good Parts book. If so, I'd suggest to wrap one line statements in curly braces.

Comment: How is that distinct from `curly:false`? Have you tried it? Did you see what I saw? It seems to me the code is indented properly. 4 spaces.  As I said, it barfs ONLY on those lines.  Also - JSHINT seems to want the statement that gets executed if the condition is true, to be indented the same as the `if` itself. Which is obviously wrong. I updated the post to show this.